# What is wrong with this particular usage of 'acabar de [+ infinitive]'?

Tags: vocabulario

I'm creating a language lesson and I'd like to include an example sentence for 'acabar de', in the infinitive.

I came up with the following sentence, but my native Spanish speaking friend says it's incorrect:

> Era rudo **acabar de llegar**, siendo que el evento comenzó hace una hora.
>   *It was rude to have just arrived, being that the event started an hour ago.*

My friend had to leave before she could explain why the sentence is incorrect, so now I turn to this community. What is wrong with the sentence?

Comment: "rudo" is a false cognate. We generally don't translate "rude" as "rudo" but as "descortés" or "de mala educación". Apart from that, your example sounds strange. "acabar de llegar" does not mean "llegar recién entonces" (to have arrived only then = so late).

Comment: Voting to close.  You might be able to rescue this question by limiting it to asking about usage of "acabar" -- but please don't ask us to proofread your brute force translation of an English sentence, or fish for the translation of a particular word such as "rude" in this way. // Note that you seem to be hoping for too much from Google Translate.

Comment: Thanks @aparente001 for the feedback. I'll update the question (hopefully to something that is appropriate).

Comment: Relevant discussion in Meta about this question: [Let's not answer questions that are not well posed](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2681/1674)

Comment: @walen "rudo" would not sound right in that sentence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your example is not ungrammatical but semantically dubious. If we change "rudo" to "descortés" or "de mala educación" as I suggested in my comment on your question and "comenzó" to "había comenzado" (perhaps even in English "being that the event **had started an hour before**" would be more appropriate), the result would be somewhat better:

> Era de mala educación acabar de llegar, siendo que el evento había comenzado hacía una hora.

I'd say that the sentence above is unlikely to occur in Spanish, because -- as I also said in my comment above -- the verb phrase "acabar de llegar" is generally neutral, and your sentence seems to attribute a negative meaning to it, as if it meant: "llegar tan tarde".

If you need to use the infinitive "acabar" rather than a tensed form of that verb, a more reasonable example could be:

> Era raro acabar de llegar y ya sentirse como en casa. (It was odd to have arrived so recently and already feel at home.)

Notice that "arriving recently" does not have the negative connotation of "arriving late".

Comment: "Era raro acabar de llegar y ya sentirse como en casa" would be more likely to be expresses as "Era raro llegar y en seguida etc."

Comment: I see nothing wrong with that. Compare with: *Era penoso acabar de casarse y ya estar discutiendo.*

Comment: That sentence sounds a bit more convincing but for me it seems much more likely that that idea would be expressed something like this: *Es penoso, acaban de casarse y ya están discutiendo*, or *Era penoso, acababan de casarse y ya estaban discutiendo.*

Comment: Interesting: I came across the desired construction, but it has a different meaning: "[En] la época de los siglos XVIII, XIX y XX[,] España tiene que acabar de luchar contra la revolución religiosa, con la que ya luchó en la época anterior." http://hispanoteca.eu/Landeskunde-Spanien/Historia/Uso%20ideol%C3%B3gico%20de%20la%20resistencia%20hispana%20contra%20Roma.htm Here it means, "Spain must finish fighting etc."

Comment: @aparente001 "acabar de" can mean both things, "just did" or "finish doing". An infinitival clause is very often equivalent to a noun clause: *Era penoso acabar de casarse y ya estar discutiendo = Era penoso que acabaran de casarse y ya estuvieran discutiendo.* Notice that in both cases the construction after "era penoso" is the subject of the sentence.

Comment: What I was trying to say was that although something like "Era penoso que acabaran de casarse y ya estuvieran discutiendo" *could* be said, I don't think it *would* be.

Comment: @aparente001 If we speak of frequency of occurrence, the infinitive "acabar de" is not likely to occur in the first place, but that's what OP needed.